# How long does it take for disturbed water to stop making sound?

Tags: time, water, oscillators

Suppose I have a bowl with water or another liquid. The water from the bowl is perfectly quiet.
Then I throw a stone in the water and I wait.
How can I calculate the time after which the water is perfectly quiet again?

Comment: In the amount of time it would take you to calculate it, you'd be better off just doing the experiment and timing it

Comment: You can't since it depends on the shape and size (and depth) of the bowl, the size and velocity of the stone, and what your criterion is for "perfectly quiet" .

Comment: The bowl is cubic,the side is L and it's full with liquid.The stone is a sphere of radius R and mass m.The velocity of the stone is v and is oriented perpendicular to the surface of water.The water is "perfectly quiet" when is no wave.